# Can I connect many SX1272 (LoRa) based devices to a gateway?

Tags: design, wireless, schematics, datasheet

Simple question: Is SX1272 chip by Semtech capable of sending data to LoRa gateways?
I'm a little bit confused about LoRa and LoRaWAN. What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is **yes**, you can connect many SX127x to a gateway.

Now for the detailed explanation:

- As said by Abhilash, LoRa is the physical layer, and LoRaWAN is the MAC layer (roughly matched to the OSI model) built on top of LoRa (LoRaWAN was initially called LoRaMAC).
- LoRaWAN creates a star-of-stars network topology
- LoRaWAN gateways use the SX1301 chip and support theoretically up to 20k nodes per gateway. A more practical figure is around 1k/nodes per gateway thou.
- SX127x chips (72 and 76 are the most common ones afaik) implement only the LoRa modulation part, not the -WAN part.
- To connect an end node to a LoRaWAN gateway you need the SX127x + a LoRaWAN stack implementation (either on software or an additional MCU)
- Some end nodes, like the Microchip RN2483 ship the SX127x + an MCU with the LoRaWAN in a closed package.
- If you only have an SX127x-based module, e.g. HopeRF RFM95W, you need to add an MCU and implement the LoRaWAN stack on the software level. The most popular library is LMIC ([LoRaMAC in C](http://www.research.ibm.com/labs/zurich/ics/lrsc/lmic.html) by IBM). There are ports for Arduino as well.

Comment: Could you provide any working examples for AVR microcontrollers?

Comment: The Arduino LMIC library by matthijskooijman (https://github.com/matthijskooijman/arduino-lmic) is the one where most effort has been invested recently. It works on the ATmega 328p (e.g. Arduino UNO), but the memory is almost filled, so it is probably best to aim for a ATmega1280 instead. Work is underway to improve the AES implementation and free-up at least 8kb of the lib's size.

Comment: 1. After compiling an example from the library Arduino IDE shows that this sketch uses 28,808 bytes (89%) of program storage space. So, if my program uses only 3 KB, it is alright to use ATmega 328p?
2. ATmega1280 is a bit expensive, how about ATmega64A?

Comment: I have never tried one of those, but I guess it should work. If you try them, I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 1):

- LoRa contains only the link layer protocol and is perfect to be used
  in P2P communications between nodes. LoRa modules are a little
  cheaper that the LoRaWAN ones. It works in the 868 and 900MHz bands.
- LoRaWAN includes the network layer too so it is possible to send the
  information to any Base Station already connected to a Cloud
  platform. LoRaWAN modules may work in the 868/900/433MHz bands.